# char* from memory address

Tags: c, char

Suppose some memory location 0xF0000 contains four character string `"four"` .

so is this valid:

```
char *mem = (char*) 0xF0000;
```

and then is mem[0] == 'f' ?

Comment: Do you mean, "and then is `mem[0]==f`"?

Comment: `mem[0]` compares equal to `'f'` (the character literal), not necessarily `f` (which is a name, perhaps of a variable, which perhaps holds the value `'f'` but could just as well not exist or exist but hold a different value). I assume `'f'` is what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it is. If the memory is mapped with the correct permissions (write) it should make no difference whatsoever to the operating system.

An easy way to test this is using `gdb`. You can break and change the value of `mem` an make it point to some memory, right before an instruction tries to change it.

In particular, don't try to modify a string literal (`char *readonly = "mystr"`);

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is valid if 0xF0000 is the starting address of the four character string "four"

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.   If you used malloc, or allocated it on the stack, then it should behave as expected.   If you just picked that address, be aware that in general it may be overwritten by other things at any time.

Comment: If you just come from the bootloader, `unsigned char *videoram = (unsigned char *) 0xb8000;` lets you write on the screen...

Comment: interesting,  but just trying to find address of smbios entry point structure.